# How to monitor Google Alert RSS feed produced "as-it-happens"?

Tags: rss, monitoring, feed, google-alerts

I have a Google Alert, which I set to be delivered as an RSS feed *as-it-happens*

[image]

But **is polling that RSS feed the only way to get RSS feed** 
or  
**is there a way to get notified from Google alert as the feed is published from Google?** (say through a webservice, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Alerts feeds support [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) which essentially pushes notifications of updated content to you if you register on the feed's hub.

They're using the hub at pubsubhubbub.appspot.com

More info on PuSH here: http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/

Comment: Thanks, Derek, it looks like what I have been looking for

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [PubSubHubBub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) for your alerts